Will an electron release energy when it is added into an atom for which electron affinity value is negative (endothermic)?
According to my understanding, when an electron is added into an atom, it emits energy in the form of photons because it is a form of de-excitation or relaxation. This is when electron affinity will be positive (exothermic). But there is one case where energy must be provided to an electron for it to overcome the repulsive forces of the electrons of the atom in which it is going to be added. Now, in this case I think the electron will still release its energy in the form of photons when it is added. However, because net energy change (Energy released in the form of photons - Energy provided to the electron) is negative (endothermic) therefore in this case we say the electron affinity of such atoms is negative.
Is this understanding of Electron Affinity correct?
